# Can Thrawn derive tactical information from a species' music?

Tags: star-wars, music, art, star-wars-thrawn

Thrawn has the amazing ability to study a species' art (sculptures and paintings) and somehow figure out the intrinsic way the species waged war in conjunction with how they create. I’m not asking how Thrawn can do this and don’t want to; but if Thrawn was dealing with a species that had no physical art, could he study their sheet music or listen to their songs to achieve the same effect? Music is a form of art after all. Is it theoretically possible? I also found no sources of him doing this but admit that I haven’t read all of Legends Thrawn.

Comment: Listen to the lyrics of "The Star Spangled Banner" and understand how/where/why it was written, and the answer is "high probability of yes".

Comment: Well... maybe back then... Warfare has evolved since then. If he tried that today, he would get something very different from current human warfare.

Answer (score 4):

Thrawn says in *[Thrawn: Treason](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thrawn:_Treason)* that music is 'seldom of use to him'. So, not *never*, but rarely.

> “I study it. Do you like art?”
> “A little.” Her voice still holds weariness, but now also holds interest. “I like music better.” Her eyes return to the sculpture they focused on a moment ago.
>
> **“Music is seldom of use to me.** Do you like this sculpture?”

---

<sub><sup>Personally, I truly don’t understand why this might be. Music is the closest thing to a species’ language, their history is literally told in their music in the clearest way.</sup></sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a good start, but you could improve your answer by supplying the exact quote.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the relevant quote and de-emphasising the personal commentary.

Comment: Welp. I have Thrawn: Treason on my shelf but this does not make me want to read it.

Comment: @Stef I find a good rule of thumb with Star Wars is: disregard anything outside the movies and animation (and often, disregard most of that too) until they've been shown to stand the test of time. This means you may have to wait for a decade or two, but who cares -- in galactic terms, it's effectively nothing. PS: I'm betting Thrawn: Treason won't make it past this test :P